# Raphael getPixelColour

Tags: raphael

I have a colour with rgb values 17, 30, 62.
I did linear gradient fill of a rect with this colour.
On mouse over of rect i want to change the colour value in a text box.
Is there any function or ratio to increase and decrease RGB values programatically
Then i can get the colour back with Raphael.rgb

Comment: At present i cant find a function in Raphael that returns pixel colour on providing X,Y value

Comment: In your colour picker example, you are increasing RGB values on scroll of mouse.

Comment: How to calculate the RGB value when i scroll. I am clear with the logic written in colour picker.

Comment: http://raphaeljs.com/picker.html - the colour is #111e3e for rgb 17,30,62. in the url the rgb range is from (0,0,0) to (69,123,255)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raphael cannot help you get the color at a specified pixel, as it only deals with vector graphics (SVG/VML). The rendering is done by the browser.

In the color picker example, the color is obtained from the coordinates in the circle -- the picker knows beforehand, which color it would find in a specified point. It **does not** check the color of the pixel under the cursor.

If you have a linear gradient with known edge colors it is a matter of linear interpolation to figure out the color of the gradient in any point (unless there is some transparency involved). Find the distance from the two anchor points of the gradient, estimate the relative distance to each and combine the colors using these coefficients.